# Why does the magnetic field of the induced current oppose the change in the external magnetic field?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

Why does the magnetic field of the induced current oppose the change in the external magnetic field?
 please help me to solve this 
Link:http://d2vlcm61l7u1fs.cloudfront.net/media%2F4dc%2F4dc03c3b-daa0-43f6-aab2-3f40636f4897%2FphpbKHpra.png

Comment: Your question was put on hold because you linked the examination. Your question may be was answered in the past. See the links right of this page.

Comment: but that is not helpful.It is just some mathematical steps

Answer (score 1):

If it were otherwise, it would violate conservation of energy: 
Consider what would happen if the magnetic field of the induced current would *enhance* the external mangnetic field: then the induced current would increase, in turn increasing the magnetic field and so on.

You would ge a runaway increase in magnetic field and hence an unlimited energy source from nothing.